# Unrecognized selector sent to instance error message from UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, unrecognized-selector

I have a UIButton that is added to a tableview programmatically. The problem is that when it is touched I run into the **unrecognized selector sent to instance** error message.

```
    UIButton *alertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];     
    [alertButton addTarget:self.tableView action:@selector(showAlert:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    alertButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 20.0, 160.0, 40.0);

    [self.tableView addSubview:alertButton];
```

and here's the alert method which I want to trigger when the InfoDark UIButton is touched:

```
- (void) showAlert {
        UIAlertView *alert = 
         [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My App" 
                                    message: @"Welcome to ******. \n\nSome Message........" 
                                   delegate:nil 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok you have two problems.
one is the selector issue as stated above, but your real problem is:

```
[alertButton addTarget:self.tableView 
                action:@selector(showAlert:) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This is the wrong target, unless you have subclassed UITableView to respond to the alert.

you want to change that code to:

```
[alertButton addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(showAlert) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 5):

**The reason of Crash  :** your `showAlert` function prototype must be `- (void) showAlert:(id) sender`.

Use below code

```
- (void) showAlert:(id) sender {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My App" message: @"Welcome to ******. \n\nSome Message........" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

As Jacob Relkin says in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356667/dynamic-button-problem-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance/3356769#3356769):

> Because you included a colon (:) in
>   your selector argument to addTarget,
>   the receiving selector must accept a
>   parameter. The runtime doesn't
>   recognize the selector
>   @selector(buttonTouched:), because
>   there isn't a method with that name
>   that accepts a parameter. Change the
>   method signature to accept a parameter
>   of type id to resolve this issue.

Comment: I changed the  showAlert method to showAlert:(id)sender. does the  action:@selector(showAlert:) change at all? thank you

Comment: @hanumanDev : Change only to showAlert:(id)sender, let your action in method as it (Do'nt change action:@selector(showAlert:)).

Comment: I did that, only changing the showAlert:(id)sender (in both the .h and .m files) but it still crashes.

Comment: I ended up doing it in IB instead and changed the method to an IBAction and it works. I couldn't see what my mistake was. thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 3):

Jhaliya is correct, but here's a brief explanation of why.

When you configured the button's target, you defined the selector like this:

```
@selector( showAlert: )
```

The colon (:) establishes a method signature for the selector requiring one argument. However, your method was defined as `-showAlert`, taking no arguments, so your object did not actually implement the method you told the `UIButton` to invoke. Redefining your method as shown by Jhaliya will work, as will changing your button target's selector to:

```
@selector( showAlert )
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I tried the @selector( showAlert ) and it still crashes with unrecognized selector error. I must be doing something else wrong perhaps.